# Gem - require filename and path

Tags: ruby, rubygems

With any given gem is there a way to determine what you need to `require` to use the gem?

e.g. I had a look at this issue on github and it's clearly not obvious in this case what file needed to be used in the `require`.

https://github.com/mark-nery/craigslist_scraper/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bundler (http://bundler.io/) to manage your gems. You'll want to run `bundle init` in terminal to create a gemfile.

In the gemfile declare all of your dependent gems, for example:

```
gem "sqlite3"
gem "pry"
```

Then on your *environment.rb* file, require bundler and the gems should all be required. On the last line, require the files that actually contain your code.

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require

Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "[ENTER DIRECTORY PATH HERE]", "ENTER FILE TYPE HERE")].each {|f| require f}
#=> Example: Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/models", "*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```